# Creating a custom list plot with dates

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, date-and-time

We have the following data

```
data = {{2000, 30, 4}, {2001, 15, 4}, {2002, 5, 5}, {2003, 27, 4}, {2004, 11, 4}, {2005, 1, 5}, 
        {2006, 23, 4}, {2007, 8, 4}, {2008, 27, 4}, {2009, 19, 4}, {2010, 4, 4}, {2011, 24, 4},
        {2012, 15, 4}, {2013, 5, 5}, {2014, 20, 4}, {2015, 12, 4}, {2016, 1, 5}, {2017, 16, 4},
        {2018, 8, 4}, {2019, 28, 4}, {2020, 19, 4}}
```

where the first column indicates the year, the second column the date, and the third column the month (April or May).

I want to create a custom list plot with a horizontal axis the year and the vertical axis starting from April 1 up to May 31. Any suggestions?

(By the way, the dates correspond to the Orthodox Easter)

**EDIT**

Using @kglr's approach

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Using @kglr's Update 3 we get

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data2 = DateObject[{#[[1]], #[[3]], #[[2]]}] & /@ data;

values = #["ISOYearDay"] -  DateObject[{#["Year"], 4, 1}]["ISOYearDay"] & /@ data2;

labels = DateString[#, {"Month", "/", "Day"}] & /@ data2;

DateListPlot[values -> labels, {data[[1, 1]]},
  Mesh -> Full, ImageSize -> Large, FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

**Update:** Add vertical ticks from April 1st to May 31st:

```
DateListPlot[values, {data[[1, 1]]}, Mesh -> Full, ImageSize -> Large, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Transpose[{values, labels}], None}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

To get less cluttered vertical ticks use custom ticks:

```
ClearAll[vTicks]
vTicks[nt_: 10] := Module[{vf = #["ISOYearDay"] - 
      DateObject[{#["Year"], 4, 1}]["ISOYearDay"] &[DateObject@#] &, 
    from = AbsoluteTime@{2000, 4, 1}, to = AbsoluteTime@{2000, 5, 31}}, 
   MapAt[vf, #, {All, 1}] & @ Select[from <= #[[1]] <= to &][
    System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[ {from, to}, nt, {"Month", "/", "Day"}]]];

DateListPlot[values, {data[[1, 1]]}, Mesh -> Full, ImageSize -> Large, 
 FrameTicks -> {{vTicks[], None}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
 GridLines -> {None, vTicks[10][[All, 1]]}]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** Loss off horizontal minor ticks mention in OP's update is likely to be version/os related.

Both in version 11.3.0 (Windows 10 /64 bit) and in version 12.0 (Wolfram Cloud) we do see the minor ticks in the date axis:

```
randomvalues = RandomInteger[{1, 61}, 201];
DateListPlot[randomvalues, {1900}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{vTicks[], Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

**Update 3:** Custom ticks with major ticks every 50 years and minor ticks every 5 years:

```
dTicks = Join[{AbsoluteTime[{#}], ToString@#, {.02, 0}} & /@ Range[1900, 2100, 50], 
  {AbsoluteTime[{#}], "", {.01, 0}} & /@ Range[1900, 2100, 5]];

SeedRandom[1]
randomvalues = RandomInteger[{1, 61}, 201];

DateListPlot[randomvalues, {1900}, ImageSize -> Large, Mesh -> All, 
 FrameTicks -> {{vTicks[], Thread[{vTicks[][[All, 1]], ""}]}, {dTicks, Automatic}},
 GridLines -> {None, vTicks[][[All, 1]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: A good start! But if the values are much more, let's say from 1900 to 2100, then all the labels are almost on top of each other. Can we delete the labels and have a vertical axis starting from April 1, to May 31?

Comment: When I apply the new code to my actual data I have no vertical ticks. It seems that your approach works only for the test data, while it should work for any given range of years, let's say from 1900 to 2100.

Comment: See my edit. The vertical ticks are fine but now I don't have small ticks at the horizontal axis.

Comment: I have version 12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) and I cannot reproduce the minor ticks.

Comment: See my new edit. Now the ticks in the lower horizontal axis seem correct (even though the major and minor ticks are the same) but the minor ticks are missing in the upper horizontal axis.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, try `FrameTicks -> {{vTicks[], Thread[{vTicks[][[All, 1]], ""}]}, {dTicks, All}}` or `FrameTicks -> {{vTicks[], Thread[{vTicks[][[All, 1]], ""}]}, {dTicks, Thread[{dTicks[[All, 1]],""}]}}`

Comment: I give up! Now the lower axis has only minor ticks and the upper axis only major ticks!

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, this should work: `FrameTicks -> {{vTicks[], Thread[{vTicks[][[All, 1]], ""}]}, {dTicks,   dTicks /. {a_, _String, c_} :> {a, "", c}}}`